# Java sending a mail via tomcat server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a mail via android application, the mail has to be sent through my server (because the mail API of Gmail need username and password so, I don't want that my data be in the code itself)

but I got this error of socketTimeOutException.
I can increase the timeout but then I cannot do anything until the response received, and it takes like 25 seconds.
and if I put the sending function in a thread it doesn't send the mail at all.

this is the code of the server:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
    try {
        System.out.println("Post ForgotMypass");
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(LogIn.host, 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("Users");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("usersCollection");

        // get a myUser object and cheack for jobs
        String json = request.getParameter("JSONObj");
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) jp.parse(json);

        String mail = (String) temp.get("mail");
        if (mail != null) {
            BasicDBObject searchQuer = new BasicDBObject();
            searchQuer.put("Mail", mail);
            DBObject Item = collection.findOne(searchQuer);
            if (Item != null) {

                JSONParser jp2 = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject Is = (JSONObject) jp2.parse(Item.toString());
                JSONObject I = (JSONObject) Is.get("_id");
                String id = (String) I.get("$oid");

                if (id != null) {
                    String Dmail = URLDecoder.decode(mail, "UTF-8");

                    SendMailSSL.SendMail(Dmail, 4, id);

                    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
                    res.put("Status", "true");
                    res.writeJSONString(out);
                    response.getOutputStream().println(out.toString());
                    System.out.println("mail sent succesfully");
                } else {
                    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
                    res.put("Status", "falseNoMail");
                    System.out.println("ver false no mail");
                    res.writeJSONString(out);
                    response.getOutputStream().println(out.toString());
                }
            } else {
                StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
                res.put("Status", "ObjectdoesntExists");
                System.out.println("ver ObjectdoesntExists");
                res.writeJSONString(out);
                response.getOutputStream().println(out.toString());
            }
        } else {// id is null
            StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
            res.put("Status", "falseIdNUll");
            System.out.println("ver falseIdNUll");

            res.writeJSONString(out);
            response.getOutputStream().println(out.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        res.put("Status", "false");
        System.out.println("ver false");

        res.writeJSONString(out);
        response.getOutputStream().println(out.toString());
    }

}
```

and:

```
public static void SendMail(String to, int typeOfMessage, String UserID) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("adress"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        /*
         * all the type of messages
         */
        if (typeOfMessage == 1) {
            message.setSubject("title");
            message.setText("text");
        }else if (typeOfMessage == 2){ 
            message.setSubject("title");
            message.setText("text");
        }else if (typeOfMessage == 3){ 
            message.setSubject("title");
            message.setText("text");
        }else if (typeOfMessage == 4){ 
            message.setSubject("title");
            message.setText("text");
        }




        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

so, somebody has an idea how to avoid that problem.
more specific , to send the mail via the server but after that, I sent the response somehow to the android client, so he doesn't have to wait for 25 seconds.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your android app should send the request in a separate thread, because sending it through the main thread will block the GUI of your app. The Tomcat-Server handles requests in different threads by default. Thus you need not starting separate threads inside of the request handling. You can start a new thread like this (see docs for `java.lang.Thread`):

```
    Thread theThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // send the request to the tomcat server
        }
    });
    theThread.start();
```